# Multi object tracking using CV2

Tags: python, opencv, video, object-detection, motion

I have some code in which you input a video, and then use background subtraction via cv2 to produce contours over a certain threshold, drawing a bounding box over them. On its own this acts simply to identify objects/motion in the video. I then go on to track the change in x and y over coordinate points of the contours to print on screen what direction the object is moving, drawing on a motion track behind the object to the frame.

However, the code cannot distinguish the different contours as separate objects. When only one object is present, it works great. When it detects more than one object/contour, the motion is all over the place as you would  expect.

I have been doing some research and it seems optical flow might be the best solution, but I'm not really sure if it applies to this situation, nor how to integrate it into the code I already have.

Is optical flow the best solution, and how can I implement it into the code? I have read this page but it doesn't follow the background subtraction or contour finding that my code currently follows. The result I want is objects/contours being tracked separately, so I can filter out any moving in a fashion/direction I don't want. Below is a small bits from my code to demonstrate my method. I follow these outlines: https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/21/opencv-track-object-movement/

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

```
# example of bg subtraction
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)

(_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, desired_th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)   

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts) #cnts ie contours, getting the outline

# motion
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)             #find the largest contour (based on its area)
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)   #compute the minimum enclosing circle and the centroid of the object.
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
            
            if radius > 10:                                 #minimum pixel radius
                cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),(0, 255, 255), 2) #draw the minimum enclosing circle surrounding the objec
                cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)       #draw the centroid
                pts.appendleft(center)                          #update the list of pts containing the center (x, y)-coordinates of the object
        
        for i in np.arange(1, len(pts)):            # loop over the set of tracked points
        
            if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                continue
            
            if counter >= 5 and i == 10 and pts[i-10] is not None: #check if enough points have been accumulated in buffer
                dX = pts[i-10][0] - pts[i][0]        #compute difference between x and y
                dY = pts[i-10][1] - pts[i][1]
                (dirX, dirY) = ("", "")             #reinitialise direction in txt variables
                
                if np.abs(dX) > 10:                         #ensure significant movement in x direction
                    dirX = "East" if np.sign(dX) == 1 else "West"
                if np.abs(dY) > 10:                           #eg 20 as in, 20 pixel difference. make smaller to detect smaller movements, and vice versa
                    dirY = "South" if np.sign(dY) == 1 else "North" # Python reverses eg top of frame is pixel 0 and bottom is eg 780
                if dirX != "" and dirY != "":               #handles when both directions are not empty
                    direction = "{}-{}".format(dirY, dirX)  #ie north west
                else:                             # otherwise, only one direction is non-empty
                    direction = dirX if dirX != "" else dirY
            
            #compute the thickness of the line and draw the connecting lines
            thickness = int(np.sqrt(buffer / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
            cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)
```

Comment: Using [Optical Flow](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html) seems like a reasonable choice for getting started. You can choose from either sparse or dense methods. Let's opt the sparse method for now `cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`. The third argument `prevPts` takes in a collection of points (`float` data type) as input. You can try passing the centroids of each contour as input and analyze how it works. (This is just a suggestion, I haven't tried it myself)

Comment: One of the problems is I do things like filter the contours eg by area (disregard small contours), erode the image, dilate with kernel, filter for colour etc. This requires the image to be turns to black with contours over the threshold in white (as opposed to simply turning the frame grey scale (eg check out the video showing similar results down the page here https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/). Optical flow requires grey scale instead, so all that filtering gets ignored

Comment: Essentially as I understand it, optical flow doesn't take contours as a parameter

Comment: optical flow won't save you. don't go there. your problems start way before that. -- your first problem is not being able to turn one background segmentation mask into multiple pieces. you already know about findContours, so why are you not **using** the multiple contours you get? you are simply taking the largest contour, which will obviously ignore any smaller contours. what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Well I'm not really sure how to distinguish them. I want to tell the code to track different contours as separate objects from frame to frame, bearing in mind the objects appear and pass through the screen so are not there for the full video. At the moment the code treats all the contours as the same object. This is why I thought optical flow, as I need to write something to the effect of: If the contour (cnt) is close to a cnt in the previous frame, treat as same object and store the coordinate path. If no cnt is nearby, object has gone. If cnt is far, different object, store as new variable.

Comment: So findcontours just gives me some tuples, and the pts variable is a deque of co-ordinates as if all contours were the same object. So when I do the motion tracking, the 'trail' goes all over the screen and direction is a mess because findcontours finds contours afresh frame to frame mixing up all the different objects present in the video